# Get a count of users in a specific OU and its sub OU's

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking for a PowerShell script that will get me:

1. The name of the `OU's`
2. The count of the number of AD users in each `OU`.

I have found this:

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “ou=Users,ou=A1,dc=contoso,dc=com”).count
```

This does exactly what I want, but I would have to type in each `OU` name. The problem is that we have 100+ `OU's`.  The specific `OU` I'm wanting to run this in is `contoso.com\cmsg\users`  under the `cmsg\users` is where the 100+ `OU's` reside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose you come at this from another angle. Each ad user contains information about its parent container. Since you are already returning all users. Lets use that to determine the counts. Caveat being that if you have user-less OU's they would not show in the results.

```psh
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties CN | 
    Select-Object @{Label='ParentContainer';Expression={$_.Distinguishedname -replace "CN=$($_.cn),"}} | 
    Group-Object -Property ParentContainer | 
    Select-Object Name,Count
```

You can of course still use `-SearchBase` to narrow the scope of `Get-ADUser`.

If this is not what you wanted your next solution would require output from [Get-ADOrganizationalUnit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617236.aspx).

```
$ous = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=Users,ou=CMSG,dc=contoso,dc=com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$ous | ForEach-Object{
    [psobject][ordered]@{
        OU = $_
        Count = (Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "$_").count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the PowerShell command to Get a count of users in a specific OU.

```
(Get-ADObject -Filter * -SearchBase "path of your OU").Count
```

Comment: Nice, but a full example like this would be better: `(Get-ADObject -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=computers,DC=yourdomain,DC=local").Count`

Comment: Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Format-Table Name, DistinguishedName -A

Answer (score 3):

I like this one - outputs exactly what original poster was after:

```
$root_ou = "ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com"
$User = get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase $ou -SearchScope Subtree | Select @{Name="OU";Expression={$_.distinguishedName -match "cn=.*?,OU=(?<OU>.*)" | Out-Null;$Matches.OU}}
$User | Group -Property OU | Select Name,Count
```

Output looks like this

```
Name                                                       Count
----                                                       -----
Office 1,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com                1230
Office 2,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com                390
Office 3,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com                90
Office 4,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com                10
```

To find the DistinguishedName of the root_ou you're after:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Format-Table Name, DistinguishedName -A
```

Comment: Eric Nord - thank you for this.  i was looking for the same thing and your script worked pretty good.  had to fix one small thing to make it work and that was to change $ou in your script to $root_ou.

i also added a          | sort count      at the end of the last line of the script to sort by count.

is there a way to then get a grand total of the count as well?

Answer (score 0):

If there are not many OU's a simple way is to select all in each OU and hit properties. This will bring up a total count for that OU. You can add each of them together after gathering counts.

Answer (score 0):

in ADUC click **View** > **Customize View** > enable **Description bar**

Comment: the Question is for a powershell script ... you might want to add to your Answer just why it IS an answer. [*grin*]

Answer (score -2):

Run in python - get-aduser will show you all users

`(get-aduser -filter *).count` will count those users for you. This is all users active or disabled.

Comment: This is unrelated to the OP's question. Also, why are you referring to Python? `(Get-ADUser -Filter *).Count` works in PowerShell.